# ¿Como obtener el nombre de la base de datos a la que estoy conectado en MySQL con Java?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Hola programadores innovadores, quisiera saber si se puede obtener el nombre del schema o base de datos a la que estoy conectado al establecer la conexion en MySQL con java, si se puede, ¿Me dirian comó?

Ya intente con en DataBaseMetaData pero ni con el uso de ese objeto pude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dices que usaste DataBaseMetaData, pero usaste el metodo  getUrl()?
`connection.getMetaData().getURL()`

Si no te sirve, prueba usando Catalog como explica en esta respuesta de SOeng:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441303/get-the-connected-mysql-database-name-jdbc